# Pyinstaller - WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: runtime-error, pyinstaller

Hello learned readers,

I'm having some trouble creating an exe using pyinstaller, whereby during run time, I'm receiving the error message:

```
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\out00-PYZ.pyz\shapely.geometry", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\out00-PYZ.pyz\shapely.geometry.base", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\out00-PYZ.pyz\shapely.coords", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\out00-PYZ.pyz\shapely.geos", line 15, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\out00-PYZ.pyz\shapely.libgeos", line 184, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\out00-PYZ.pyz\ctypes", line 365, in __init__
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

As far as I know, this is a dll problem. However it does not specify which once is causing the problem. I've debugged using --log-level=debug and pasted this below. I've also checked the warning message from pyinstaller and haven't been able to discern the cause of the error.

Any thought of suggestions as to what could be causing this error?

Many thanks

Snip taken from the output of the buildtime:

```
24094 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.MFC to dependent assemblies of final executable
24222 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
24223 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86.manifest
24223 INFO: Searching for file mfc90.dll
24225 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86\mfc90.dll
24225 INFO: Searching for file mfc90u.dll
24225 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86\mfc90u.dll
24225 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90.dll
24225 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86\mfcm90.dll
24225 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90u.dll
24225 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86\mfcm90u.dll
26147 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none ...
26147 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57.manifest
26148 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
26148 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll
26148 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
26148 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcp90.dll
26149 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
26149 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcm90.dll
26516 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
27055 INFO: Using Python library C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll
27253 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\warngis_helper2.txt
27286 INFO: checking PYZ
27286 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
27286 INFO: building PYZ (ZlibArchive) out00-PYZ.toc
33585 INFO: checking PKG
33585 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
33585 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
60197 INFO: checking EXE
60197 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because GIS_Helper.exe missing
60197 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
60202 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\dist\GIS_Helper.exe
```

Comment: What does line 365 of the file `C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\out00-PYZ.pyz\ctypes\__init__.py` contain?

Comment: Having some trouble reading that file.

Comment: Having some trouble reading that. The directory stops at the out00-PYZ.pyz fiile. 

I used the scripts 'pyinstall extractor' and 'easy python decompiler'  to decompile the exe that was generated, but that only provided me with the ctypes.pyc file. I was able to read this and it references the __init__, but I wasn't able to find it.

I've copied the uncompiled ctypes.pyc file here:

http://pasted.co/a8edc86e

Comment: Any idea how to unzip a pyz file? I'm guessing the ctypes init is located in there. I just can't get to it. Thanks again for your help Yoel :)

Comment: There are some pretty good hints in the traceback and build log: [libgeos.py](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/1.5.12/shapely/libgeos.py#L178), which loads geos.dll on Windows, and [ZlibArchive](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/v2.1/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_archive.py#L258), which uses [zlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) compression.

Comment: Thank you, after adding shapely.libgeos to the hidden modules in the spec file, the error messages progressed.

Frustrating that the error message changes from giving you the name of the module to not doing so. Still learning I suppose. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the geos_c.dll file. Pyinstaller was not picking it up automatically. I tried copying this to the build directory where the spec file was being executed from. This wasn't enough however and the solution was to edit the spec file to include the geos_c.dll

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['GIS_Helper.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Hp\\PycharmProjects\\GISdev'],
             hiddenimports=['scipy.linalg.cython_blas', 'scipy.linalg.cython_lapack', 'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx', 'multiprocessing', '_multiprocessing', 'multiprocessing.process', 'multiprocessing.util', 'ctypes.util', 'pandas.util', 'distutils.util', 'shapely'],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)



a.binaries=['geos_c.dll', 'geos_c.dll', 'BINARY'],

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [('v',None,'OPTION')],
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='GIS_Helper.exe',
          debug=True,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```