# PYZ file extension

Tags: runtime-error, ctypes, pyinstaller, pyz

I have searched but can find no way to read PYZ files. I know they are a type of zip file, but I can not read them by way of a zip program.

This is in reference to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669161/pyinstaller-windowserror-error-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found?noredirect=1#comment53189478_32669161) where I need access to the _init__ file inside a directory structure that is created by pyinstaller when attempting to build an exe. During this process, a out00-PYZ.pyz file is created, and the error references a file inside the PYZ.

The thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303122/how-to-decompile-files-from-pyinstaller-pyz-file) describes how to decompile from an EXE to obtain PYC files, but doesn't work with PYZ files.

Surely there is someway to crack open this commonly used pythonic file?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had used Pyinstaller you can go to the location of directory which contains .pyz then go SHIFT and right click on directory, go to open command window here, then:
    pyi-archive_viewer out00-PYZ.pyz